# Posting Buildnotes on jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to post my uildnotes which is a html file on Jenkins. how do I achieve this?

For example I have a file 4.9.0.12_buildNotes.html and I want to show the contents of this file on my jenkins page how do I do that

Answer (score 3):

You could simply store it as a build artifact. See "Archive the artifacts" on the job configure page.

Answer (score 0):

If your notes are brief, you may want to use the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

Check out Example 1.  It puts text directly on the build page.